# Drupal sites/default/settings.php issue on pantheon

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pantheon

I am a complete noob at this site business, and I'm facing what seems to be a very simple problem with my Drupal site (hosted on pantheon):
[image]

I don't know where this file located nor how to copy it to the other .php files (whose location I also don't know). I would really appreciate *detailed* help.

Answer (score 0):

That's file that holds your configuration info, i.e. database user info.

When you run normal Drupal installation process drupal creates that file for you, based on data you provide during installation process.

However in same dir there should be some "template" file called "default.settings.php" so if you really don't have settings.php rename this default.settings.php file to "settings.php", adjust it (set at least database connection data) and your site should run after that. Maybe it's a good idea too keep original default.settings.php file too.

Comment: I never ran normal Drupal installation. Instead, [pantheon](https://pantheon.io/) ran it for me. Now I don't know where to find these .php files nor how to copy/paste them..

Comment: Hmm..I never used pantheon, but there must be a way to manipulate your files. Usual way is by FTP but maybe with pantheon you must use some specific tools or something. Anyway, read carefully the error message you posted here - it explains you everything (nama and location of file).